# Timeout has no effect in NSAppleScript

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript, applescript-objc

I have a simple apple script as follows:

```
tell application id "com.adobe.InDesign"
    set sel to selection
end tell
```

This script is executed fine, but when the InDesign displaying **Save Confirm Dialog**, if I execute the script, It waits for 2 minutes (Default apple script timeout).

[image]
Save Confirm Dialog

Thus I specified timeout as follows:

```
tell application id "com.adobe.InDesign"
    with timeout of 0.2 seconds
        set sel to selection
    end timeout
end tell
```

Now If I execute above script in **AppleScript Editor** every thing is as I expected:

[image]

But when I execute same script programmatically by **NSAppleScript** the timeout has no effects and the program waits for 2 minutes:

```c
NSDictionary *errorDict;
NSString *script = 
    @"tell application id \"com.adobe.InDesign\"\n"
    @"  with timeout of 0.2 second\n"
    @"      set sel to selection\n"
    @"  end timeout\n"
    @"end tell\n"
    ;    
NSAppleScript* scr = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource: script];
[scr executeAndReturnError: &errorDict];
```

Additional description:
When my cocoa code is executing (when my app is blocked) If I execute same script in **AppleScript Editor** then my cocoa code is unblocked before 2 minutes timeout. It seems my app is blocked before apple script timeout line [?] 
How can I execute apple script same as **AppleScript Editor**?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Building your script and saving as an Application should fix this. It should be the same script but just add `on run` and `end run` at the beginning and end of the script. The way to do this is when you go to save, at the bottom of the save menu, there should be a file format dropdown. Select the "Application" option and save.

I have noticed this will nullify the "default Applescript timeout".

Comment: Thankyou, I will try this solution, And how can I use the "Application" in my project?

Comment: @mhtaqia You can run the Applescript Application via your project